# Как реализовать медиазапрос на js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, условия, media-queries

Всем привет. Подскажите как условие скрипта:

```
$('.frame').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.find('.variations_form').length) {
    var height =
      $this.find('.section h3').height() + $this.find('.container').height();
    if (height != 346) {
      $this.find('.price').css("top", (height + 32) + "px");
    }
  }
});
```

реализовать для на разрешениях мобильного устройства, т.е.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {  
          // условие для мобильных устройств
   }     
});
```

Нужно его внутри повторно прописывать или медиа запрос можно как-то реализовать внутри цикла, чтобы не создавать повторные условия?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Поясните, в чём смысл первого скрипта как он соотносится со вторым и т.д.

Comment: @Andrey Lobarev назначение первого скрипта абсолютно не важно в данном контексте - я мог вообще записать так
`$('.frame').each(function() { if (...) {...} });` но показал, что это мне нужно для абсолютного позиционирования
А нужно мне ту же самую процедуру теперь проделать для мобильных разрешений - теперь я доступнее пояснил?

Comment: Так и реализуйте, дополнительно при загрузке страницы, вызывайте события resize, если не срабатывает на мобильных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться matchMedia (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia):

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1024px)").matches) {
  $('.frame').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.find('.variations_form').length) {
      var height =
        $this.find('.section h3').height() + $this.find('.container').height();
      if (height != 346) {
        $this.find('.price').css("top", (height + 32) + "px");
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log('ПАБЕДА!!!11!')
}
```

для старых браузеров используйте полифил: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/